# Can I deploy my application with Flask using Celery on Vercel?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, vercel

I'm doing an app with Flask that need to use Celery for a background work. In local works fine, I'm using "celery -A index.celery worker -l info -P gevent" to start the broker RabbitMQ. Now I need to deploy this on Vercel but I don't know how to do it. Can I solve it using another host for the broker in AWS? I find an option for Vercel which is ServerlessQ if I can't solve it any other way.

Project GitHub Link : https://github.com/victorrmc/OfertAlert/tree/celery

I try in the Project Settings in Vercel usign the "celery -A index.celery worker -l info -P gevent" in the Development Command but not works

Error of Vercel:

```
[WARNING]   2023-09-17T13:12:25.821Z    52603464-4cb5-44dd-8e31-41304a5c6526    No hostname was supplied. Reverting to default 'localhost'
[ERROR] 2023-09-17T13:12:31.874Z    52603464-4cb5-44dd-8e31-41304a5c6526    Exception on / [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 32, in __call__
    return self.__value__
AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/kombu/connection.py", line 472, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    yield
  File "/var/task/kombu/connection.py", line 459, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "/var/task/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 318, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/kombu/connection.py", line 934, in _connection_factory
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/var/task/kombu/connection.py", line 860, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/var/task/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 203, in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
  File "/var/task/amqp/connection.py", line 323, in connect
    self.transport.connect()
  File "/var/task/amqp/transport.py", line 129, in connect
    self._connect(self.host, self.port, self.connect_timeout)
  File "/var/task/amqp/transport.py", line 184, in _connect
    self.sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "./index.py", line 18, in home
    compobador_ofertas.check_sale.delay(email, url)
  File "/var/task/celery/app/task.py", line 444, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "/var/task/celery/app/task.py", line 594, in apply_async
    return app.send_task(
  File "/var/task/celery/app/base.py", line 797, in send_task
    self.backend.on_task_call(P, task_id)
  File "/var/task/celery/backends/rpc.py", line 164, in on_task_call
    maybe_declare(self.binding(producer.channel), retry=True)
  File "/var/task/kombu/messaging.py", line 218, in _get_channel
    channel = self._channel = channel()
  File "/var/task/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 34, in __call__
    value = self.__value__ = self.__contract__()
  File "/var/task/kombu/messaging.py", line 234, in <lambda>
    channel = ChannelPromise(lambda: connection.default_channel)
  File "/var/task/kombu/connection.py", line 953, in default_channel
    self._ensure_connection(**conn_opts)
  File "/var/task/kombu/connection.py", line 459, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/var/task/kombu/connection.py", line 476, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    raise ConnectionError(str(exc)) from exc
kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```